# Getting a list of all substrings in a data frame column in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame in R, let's call it `data`.

One of the columns, `data$tags` contains strings. Each string is a comma separated list of tags (or categories that this entry relates to).

I'm trying to get a list of all available tags in the data frame.

I thought I could use one of the `apply` functions to run the column over the `strsplit` function and get one long concatenated vector with all string parts, then use `unique` to get rid of the duplicates.

I tried:

```
func_split_tags <- function(e) {
  return(unlist(strsplit(e," ")))
}
all_tags <- sapply(as.vector(data$tags), func_split_tags)
```

but that just gives me a list of the split-string vectors.

Does anyone have any idea how to make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `unlist` on it? Hard to give working code without sample input data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this is what you are looking for?

```
df <- data.frame(x = seq(1:10), s = 'I am in the city', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
as.character(unlist(sapply(df$s, function(x) strsplit(x, ' '))))
```

You could write that last line as if you don't want anything more than a simple `strsplit`:

```
unlist(strsplit(df$s, ' '))
```

Comment: I don't think you actually need the `sapply`; `strsplit` can take a vector of strings (thus why it always returns a list and you see `strsplit(foo, ' ')[[1]]` so much). I'm not sure what the `as.character` is doing either; if you need it to convert factors (probably?), you want it right around `df$s`, as it'd still fail as-is.

Comment: Perfect! The complete solution was:

(a) adding the `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` parameter

(b) to remove duplicates: `unique(as.character(unlist(sapply(data$tags, function(x) strsplit(x, ' ')))))`

Comment: @alistaire excellent point. I was going with `sapply` concept thinking general case. I was using `as.character` to remove the names returned by `sapply`.

Answer (score 0):

We could do this with `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
unlist(str_extract_all(df$s, "\\w+"))
```